# Trigger child to update

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hi I'm new to Angular and any help would be great. The parent of my component has a method to generate different rules for each picker, but the rules also change dynamically from the parent so I need to make my picker component call the disableoption method and updating its own Options when the parent has been updated.

```
<picker-component *ngFor="let parameter of product.parameters" [parameter]="parameter" [disabledOptions]="disabledOptions(parameter)"></picker-component>
```

Comment: And the code shown in the question does not work?

Comment: It works the first time, but whern the state fo the parent is changed I want the child to recall the method and update itself

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to inject the parent in the child (I'm not telling this is the best approach to your case, I'm just answering your question):

```html
  <parent> <!-- ParentComponent typescript class -->
    <child></child> <!-- ChildComponent typescript class -->
  </parent>
```

```js
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private _parentComponent: ParentComponent) {
    this._parentComponent.disabledOptions(parameter);
  }
}
```

In cases like this, a service injected in both `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent` usually is a better and easy-to-implement approach though.